# Why does this snippet fail with ``AttributeError: 'CustomAdapter' object has no attribute 'setLevel'``?

Tags: python, logging

I put the following into a file named `repro.py`, then typed `python repro.py`.  (I'm using C Python 2.7.5).  It failed with the error in the question.  The source confirms that there is no method of that name on the LoggerAdapter class, but the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LoggerAdapter) say there are:

> In addition to the above, LoggerAdapter supports the following methods of Logger, i.e. debug(), info(), warning(), error(), exception(), critical(), log(), isEnabledFor(), getEffectiveLevel(), **setLevel()**, hasHandlers(). These methods have the same signatures as their counterparts in Logger, so you can use the two types of instances interchangeably.

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?  If the latter, is it indeed possible to use the LoggerAdapter instance as a drop-in replacement for a Logger instance?

```
import logging logging.basicConfig ()

class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return '[%s] %s' % (self.extra['connid'], msg), kwargs

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'connid': '1234'}) 
adapter.setLevel (logging.WARN) 
adapter.warning ("Ahoy matey")
```

Comment: This is not going to solve your question but I believe it is `logging.WARNING` not `logging.WARN` also I tried your code if you remove the `setLevel` function call your code works (you probably already knew this)

Comment: @jramirez yep, I indeed already knew that.  That's sort of the point.

Comment: I'm convinced it's a bug, so I've reported it: http://bugs.python.org/issue19455

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not mistaken. The docs claim functionality that is not supported. The LoggerAdapter class inherits from `object`, rather than from Logger, so it only supports the methods that it explicitly defines. It does, however, store the logger instance you pass in as self.logger.

So, for now, you can do this instead:

```
adapter.logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

I agree, this is either a bug in the documentation, or a bug in the implementation, depending on how you look at it.